# Entity Framework Sum Query Awaitable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, async-await, sum

I'm trying to make a sum statement awaitable:

```
public class MyClassOne
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public class MyClassTwo
{
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
}

MyClassTwo myClassTwo = new MyClassTwo();

myClassTwo.TotalAmount = _context.MyClassOne
                                 .Where(p => p.id == 1.Sum(x => x.Amount);
```

This works as expected, except it's not awaitable and I can't figure out how to modify it to make it so.

Thanks

Comment: Use SumAsync extension

Comment: This **cannot** possibly work! You're lacking a closing bracket in your `.TotalAmount =` statement ...... shouldn't it be `.Where(p => p.id == 1).Sum(x => x.Amount);` (closing bracket after the `== 1` check? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SumAsync (EF)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.sumasync) or [SumAsync (EF Core)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.sumasync), depending on the version you're using:

```cs
myClassTwo.TotalAmount = await _context.MyClassOne
    .Where(p => p.id == 1)
    .SumAsync(x => x.Amount);
```